# Bootstrap 3 and above with row or container-fluid

Tags: twitter-bootstrap, twitter-bootstrap-3

I need help with upgrades inside Bootstrap 3. As I understand there is actually redundant element like container-fluid.
Can I use row without container-fluid as my example:

```
<div class="row">

<section class="border-box">

</section>

</div>
```

Issue is in this case if you check lower resolutions. Container will not limit padding specifications.

Can be used in this case

```
<div class="row">

<section class="border-box">

<container>

</container>

</section>

</div>
```

Is it allowed this example or header without row element?

```
<section class="border-box">

<container>

</container>

</section>

</div>
```

Answer (score 1):

The `.row` is meant to contain Bootstrap `col-*` grid columns since it uses negative margins. So, no, it wouldn't be good to use another element immediately inside a `.row`

*Per the Bootstrap docs (http://getbootstrap.com/css/#grid)..*

- Rows must be placed within a .container (fixed-width) or .container-fluid (full-width) for proper alignment and padding.
- Use rows to create horizontal groups of columns.
- Content should be placed within columns, and **only columns may be immediate children of rows**.